# Дебаг в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, webstorm, jetbrains

Недавно перешел с VSC на WebStorm и не могу понять как грамотно настроить дебаг. Существует простой проект (html,css,js). Я открываю дебаг в *index.html*, изменяю *script.js* , но изменения не применяются, а если изменяю index, то все работает (я понимаю, что дебажу *index.html*, но как тогда весь проект дебажить). Например, плагин **liveServer** в VSC обновлял страничку после изменения скрипта(достаточно было сохранить его). Как настроить то?

[image: Вот настройка Live Edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Live Edit** не перегружает страницу и не обновляет состояние приложения, поэтому изменения в коде Javascript, исполняемом при загрузке страницы, будут видны только при перезагрузке.... если меняется код, исполняемый по какому-то событию (`onclick` handler, к примеру), то вы увидите изменения сразу при наступлении этого события. То же относится и к коду, выполняемому по таймеру

В 2021.2 мы добавили новые возможности, позволяющие автоматически перезагружать странички в браузере при сохранении изменений, см. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/05/webstorm-2021-2-eap-1/#browser_pages_reload_on_save. Эта фича работает одинаково для HTML, CSS и JS и не требует запуска отладчика, т.е. аналогична **liveServer** в VSC